# common-msgs vs std-msgs?

Tags: ros, std-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When various message handling packages like actionlib, navigation, sensor, geometry are included in the common_msgs stack, why is std_msgs package separated? How is std_msgs package different from the others mentioned above, for it to be excluded from the common_msgs stack?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255674/common-msgs-vs-std-msgs-?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can only guess, but to me the following seems to be the rational behind it:

Description on `std_msgs`:

> Contains minimal messages of primitive data types and multiarrays. Intended for quick prototyping, not production use.

The full explanation/discussion can be found on [discourse.](https://discourse.ros.org/t/suggestions-for-std-srvs/1079/9)

**EDIT**

With semantics is meant that you can derive from the message name and the names of it fields what it transports. To give an example (stolen more or less from discourse ;-) ):

If you would like to send a temperature, you could just use a `std_msgs/Float` message. However, if you would inspect the message, it is not clear what this should be. Is it a temperature, and if yes in Celsius, Fahrenheit, ..., or rather air pressure or the distance to an object? All the messages says is it is a float and contains a field `data`.

If you however use a dedicated [`sensor_msgs/Temperature` message](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/jade-devel/sensor_msgs/msg/Temperature.msg), you are fairly certain that this should actually be a temperature and that this temperature should be in degree celsius (check [the source](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/jade-devel/sensor_msgs/msg/Temperature.msg) for the full description).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-27**:
Msgs in `std_msgs` wrap primitive data types, but don't add any semantics. The msg pkgs in `common_msgs` do add semantics.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-27**:
and by semantics , you mean ??

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-28**:
see edit above.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-28**:
That helped!! Thanks